# Android list view the single value of a row

Tags: android, listview

is possible get the value of a single row. 
In partycular i wont get in a string the value of id in my row of mt list with adapter.

In each row there are value id and label

Thaks a lot and sorry for my english

```
ListView list;
            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), result ,R.layout.row_meteo,
                    new String[]{"id", "label"}, new int[] {R.id.textView1,R.id.textView2});
            list.setAdapter(mSchedule);

            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    String idPlace = mSchedule.getItem(position).toString();

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," Cliccato sul luogo :"+idPlace,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {


                    TextView tv  = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1); //<---------
                    String str = tv.getText();


                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
String idPlace = mSchedule.getItem(position).toString();
```

with

```
String idPlace =((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).getText().toString();
```